# Swagger reader throws java.lang.NoSuchMethodError

Tags: java, jackson, swagger

I am trying to create API documentation in my project(Sparkjava). [I use this article][1] I wrote this parser:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude.Include;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import io.swagger.jaxrs.Reader;
import io.swagger.models.*;
import spark.Route;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class SwaggerParser {

    public static String getSwaggerJson(List<Route> routes) throws JsonProcessingException {
        Swagger swagger = getSwagger(routes);
        return swaggerToJson(swagger);
    }

    private static Swagger getSwagger(List<Route> routes) {
        Swagger swagger = new Swagger();
        swagger.info(new Info().description("User API")
                .version("V1.0")
                .title("Some random api for testing")
                .contact(new Contact().name("Serol").url("https://serol.ro")));
        swagger.schemes(Arrays.asList(Scheme.HTTP, Scheme.HTTPS));
        swagger.consumes("application/json");
        swagger.produces("application/json");
        swagger.tag(new Tag().name("swagger"));

        Reader reader = new Reader(swagger);

        for (Route route : routes) {
            try {
                reader.read(route.getClass());
            }catch (Throwable throwable){
                System.out.println(throwable);
            }
        }

        return reader.getSwagger();
    }

    public static String swaggerToJson(Swagger swagger) throws JsonProcessingException {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_EMPTY);
        return objectMapper.writeValueAsString(swagger);
    }

}
```

It works in my test application but doesn't work in the real project. I wrote init test for that:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.healthgorilla.portal.server.labnetwork.api.GetOrdersAPI;
import com.healthgorilla.portal.server.labnetwork.route.GetOrdersRoute;
import org.junit.Test;

import java.util.Collections;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;

public class SwaggerParserTest {
    @Test
    public void name() throws JsonProcessingException {
        GetOrdersAPI api = mock(GetOrdersAPI.class);
        when(api.exec()).thenReturn("");

        String swaggerJson = SwaggerParser.getSwaggerJson(Collections.singletonList(new GetOrdersRoute(api)));
        
        assertNotNull(swaggerJson);
    }
}
```

And it throws an exception:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.AnnotatedMember.getType(Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/type/TypeBindings;)Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JavaType;
```

But in the test project it works
[1]: https://serol.ro/posts/2016/swagger_sparkjava/

EDIT:

I found conflict. It newer jckson version in the project. I change my swagger dependencies

```
<!-- swagger -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.2</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.2</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
```

But it doesn't help. There are my Jackson dependencies:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.2</version>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 3):

Potentially the issue is that your dependencies(including transitive) are incompatible with your swagger version.
I don't know which build system you are using, but in maven it can be done using

```java
mvn dependency:tree
```

https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/tree-mojo.html

In gradle you may try `gradle -q dependencies --configuration scm`, more in https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/viewing_debugging_dependencies.html

Try to inspect your dependencies and their versions.

Comment: I edited my question. I found the reason for the conflict but I can not fix it.

Comment: could you please post the whole dependencies tree for swagger lib?

Answer (score 2):

Check out `springfox-boot-starter` dependency in your pom.xml.
In case with upgrade from swagger2 to swagger3 I forgotten delete dependencies with swagger2 like `springfox-boot-starter`. After that works.